# Warum wird in diesem Satz der männliche Artikel für ein weibliches Nomen verwendet („der Idee“ anstatt „die Idee“)?

Tags: noun

Ich habe eine Frage über das Geschlecht eines Nomens. Ich habe immer gedacht, dass *Idee* feminin ist. Aber ich habe einen Satz gelesen, wo *der Idee* anstatt *die Idee* benutzt wird. Hier ist ein Ausschnitt:

> Die deutschen Feste zeichneten sich immer durch etwas aus, was
>   vielleicht mit deutscher Gemütlichkeit einhergeht. **Der Idee**, dass man
>   sich so gibt, wie man ist, dass man für so ’nen kurzen Moment diese
>   ganzen Zwänge, die auf einem lasten, dass man die mal kurz über Bord
>   wirft.

([Quelle](http://www.dw.com/de/volksfeste-mit-tradition/a-18585438))

Kann man *Idee* als ein maskulines Nomen benutzen?

Answer (score 14):

Nein, *Idee* ist ein Femininum. Aber auch im Femininum kommt die Artikelform *der* vor, und zwar im Genitiv und im Dativ Singular:

> Die Ursprünge der Idee *(Gen. Sg.)*/der Ideen *(Gen. Pl.)* sind nicht mehr nachzuvollziehen.
>   Ich gebe der Idee *(Dat. Sg.)* keine Chance.

Im Text ist nicht ganz klar, woran *der Idee* sich anschließt – möglicherweise an das *mit* (*mit deutscher Gemütlichkeit, mit der Idee*). Es ist ein O-Ton, also kein schriftlich vorbereiteter Text; da sind unvollständige Sätze und Neuanfänge nicht ungewöhnlich. Auch die Wiederaufnahme des *dass* am Ende (*dass man diese ganzen Zwänge, dass man die über Bord wirft*) würde man in Schriftsprache so wohl nicht finden.

Comment: es scheint, dass die Idee hier nicht in der Form von Genitiv oder Dativ. Vielen Dank für Ihren Kommentar :ß

Comment: @Josh: Doch, das scheint sie wohl. Aber du mußt es einem Muttersprachler natürlich nicht glauben.

Comment: Füge nach "Die deutschen Feste zeichneten sich immer durch etwas aus, was vielleicht mit deutscher Gemütlichkeit einhergeht" einfach **und mit** ein, und der Satz wird auch grammatikalisch korrekt. Im Ergebnis also "und mit der Idee, dass ..."

Comment: Der Satz kann grammatikalisch nur so verstanden werden, dass der zweite Satz erläutert, was deutsche Gemütlichkeit ist. Ob das inhaltlich Sinn ergibt, ist eine andere Frage. Aber ganz sicher ist das ein Dativ, selbst wenn dieser fehl am Platze sein sollte.

Comment: Am einfachsten ist das wohl zu sehen, wenn der zweite Satz als Erklärung der deutschen Gemütlichkeit dient. Verdeutlichen kann man das so: was vielleicht mit deutscher Gemütlichkeit einhergeht: (oder , nämlich) der Idee, dass ...

Answer (score 2):

Nun: Wie in den anderen Antworten bereits erwähnt, handelt es sich hier beim Artikel nicht um einen Fehler sondern um die Dativ- Form.

Ich widerspreche allerdings meinen Vorrednern insofern, dass ich sage: die Intention des Satzes lässt sich durchaus verstehen. Hier wurde der ursprünglich vorgesehene Satz verkürzt, um Wiederholungen zu vermeiden. Komplett ausgeschrieben stünde hier dann:

> ...was vielleicht mit deutscher Gemütlichkeit einhergeht. [Was einhergeht mit] der Idee, dass man sich so gibt, wie man ist, dass man für so ’nen kurzen Moment diese ganzen Zwänge, die auf einem lasten, dass man die mal kurz über Bord wirft.

Denn wenn man den Satz so liest wie er dasteht, hat man einen unvollständigen Hauptsatz (kein Subject, kein Prädikat) mit mehreren -durch dass eingeleiteten- Nebensätzen.

Answer (score 0):

Deutsche Substantive haben eine Artikeldeklination. "die Frau", feminin, ist Nom/Akk, "der Frau" ist Gen/Dat.
https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/nomen/deklination

Answer (score -2):

Ganz sicher ist, dass der Ersteller des Transkripts einen Fehler gemacht hat. Es müsste zumindest der Punkt durch ein Komma ersetzt werden:

> ... was vielleicht mit deutscher Gemütlichkeit einhergeht, der Idee ...

Die Erklärung wäre dann, dass die deutsche Gemütlichkeit beschrieben wird und der Satz in etwa diesem entspricht:

> ... was vielleicht mit deutscher Gemütlichkeit einhergeht, also mit der Idee ...

Was folgt ist aber keine Beschreibung der deutschen Gemütlichkeit und es würde dann auch die Erklärung fehlen, was deutsche Feste auszeichnet.

Viel wahrscheinlicher ist, dass dem Sprecher ein Fehler unterlaufen ist. Es war auch nicht der einzige ^^. Es muss *"Die Idee"* heißen, denn es bezieht sich auf *"Die deutschen Feste zeichneten sich ... durch etwas aus"*.

> Die deutschen Festen zeichneten sich durch die Idee aus, dass ... Diese Idee geht vielleicht mit deutscher Gemütlichkeit einher.

Comment: Weder das Eine noch das Andere muss sein. Wenn der Sprecher oder die Sprecherin zwischen der Gemütlichkeit und der Idee eine lange Pause gemacht hat, wäre ein Komma im Transskript unangemessen, es müsste ein Punkt sein. Und der Anschluss ist auch grammatikalisch in Ordnung, denn es gibt *kein neues Verb* was einen bestimmten Kasus erfordern würde. Man kann, wie andere geschrieben haben, davon ausgehen, dass der vorherige Satz nochmal wiederholt hätte werden können, aber ausgelassen worden ist. Demnach -1